# Convert the value of a column into one row

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am new to LINQ. I have tried for a couple way but I cannot get the result I want.
Please help to solve this. LINQ to SQL in VB.NET.

I am using the Ling to SQL class to run the query to get the expected result.
After the the query result, I will use it to fill the Datagridview .
I cannot find a solution to the following question. Is there anyone can help?
Thanks.

Table:

```
bookID  authorID  authorname
111     101       Mark
222     102       Tim
333     103       John
444     104       Rebecca
111     102       Tim
111     103       John
222     104       Rebecca
```

Result should be:

```
bookID   author1     author2         author3....

111      Mark            Tim                  John

222      TIm              Rebecca          N/A or Empty

333      John            N/A or Empty    N/A or Empty

444      Rebecca      N/A or Empty    N/A or Empty
```

I have to use **LINQ** only.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! **1.** Please note that formatting your posts in a sensible manner really helps readability a lot. (I've edited it, but please, next time, take some time to do this yourself right from the start.) **2.** How is this related to VB.NET? => Please edit your question and explain what you're trying to do, show the relevant bits from your VB.NET code, and explain how it doesn't do what you expect it to. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the [`GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx) method

```
Dim results = db.Books.GroupBy(Function(b) b.bookID, Function(b) b.authorname)
```

Or if you prefer linq query syntax

```
Dim results = _
    From b In db.Books _
    Group b.authorname By bookID = b.bookID Into authorname = Group
```

Which you can use as

```
For Each group In results
    Console.Write(group.Key)
    Console.Write(":")
    For Each name As String In group 
        Console.Write("  " & name)
    Next 
    Console.WriteLine()
Next
```

outputs

```
111: Mark Tim John
222: Tim Rebecca
333: John
444: Rebecca
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response. Actually I need a query with LINQ statement only. Just modify the question.

Comment: @tim the query is the fist line in my answer. the rest is just there to demonstrate the results

Comment: By reading your code. I got the expected result. Thanks a lot.!!

Comment: actually I changed a little bit. Please see my answer. Many thanks.

Comment: @tim yes, sorry my vb.net is a little rusty. I write mostly c# these days.

Comment: Thanks for you help:) . Stackoverflow is amazing:)

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim results = From b In db.Books Group b.authorname _ 
                By bookID = b.bookID Into nameg = Group select bookid,nameg

For each gr in results 
    Console.Write(gr.bookid)
    Console.Write(":")
    For Each name As String In gr.nameg 
    Console.Write("  " & name)
Next 
Console.WriteLine()
Next
```